# ConditionalAttribute vs Debugger.IsAttached

Tags: .net, debugging, attributes, visual-studio-debugging

What is the difference between ConditionalAttribute and Debugger.IsAttached??
Which of this mechanism is better to use??

If I write:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void Method() 
{ 
   //Code
}
```

will be the same like:

```
private void Method()
{ 
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    { 
        //Code
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The attribute works for compilation. If the DEBUG flag is not set the method is omitted from the produced binary.

The Debugger is attached checks if a debugger is attached. But a debugger can be attached to any kind of build (Release, Debug etc.)

Since they are quite different, I don't think they can be compared for which one is "better". They do different things. If you want something for a debug build that should have no effect (e.g. performance) on a production build at all, then use the attribute.